# Надо с полок муку соскребсти-таки/соскрести-таки

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Надо с полок муку соскребсти-таки/соскрести-таки.

Comment: Верно: _соскрести_. Буква Б здесь не нужна.

Comment: Но есть же слово *соскребу*.

Comment: А вот слова _соскребсти_ нет в словарях. Только _соскрести_.